# Get file name in custom layer after training Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Is there any way to get the current batch's file name in a custom_layer?

I need to concate new_image and feature map in custom_layer , I need file name to get the new_image.

```
class custom_layer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(custom_layer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        feature_map = inputs
        # get file name and new_image for concate
        file_name = 
        return tf.concat([feature_map, concate_image], axis=-1)

new_layer = custom_layer()
conv_base = tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2(weights=None,include_top=False , input_shape=(299,299,3))

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(New_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(7,activation='softmax')) 

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


train_generator = DataGenerator(partition['train'], labels, **params, shuffle=True)
valid_generator = ValTest_DataGenerator(partition['validation'], labels, **params, shuffle=False)
test_generator = ValTest_DataGenerator(partition['test'], labels, **params, shuffle=False)
```